# How to add a circle inside of a black or white box in CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css

For instance, I am trying to make a checkers table out of a HTML table. This is working well, however I need to add the actual chips, AKA circles inside of my square boxes.

```
 <tbody>
           <tr><th>8<td style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc; margin-left: 30px;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid #222222; margin-left: 30px;">....
```

How exactly would i add a circle inside of the box?

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc; margin-left: 30px;">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Create an element (div or whatever) with equal width and height and set its border-radius to 50%.

Comment: does it need to be inside the /td?

Comment: Only if that’s where you want it to appear.